# Store file in storage folder using PutFileAS() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to save file to storage folder laravel ; i have tried the following ways to create file and store at path1 - path2 ; In both cases I got

> " Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \
>   FileNotFoundException The file "The file conten goes here ...." does
>   not exist "

```
  public function saveToStorage()
{


    $content='The file conten goes here ....';
    $path1=Storage::PutFileAS('txtFiles',new File($content),'filename1.txt');
    $path2=Storage::PutFileAS('txtFiles',file_get_contents($content),'filename2.txt');

}
```

Comment: `Storage::disk('local')->put('txtFiles/' . time() . 'textFilename.txt', 'Contents is this is what is there ');` This way is working fine , but what i need to make laravel automaticly stream the big files to storage ** using putFileAs() ** function .